# getView() not working properly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

Look at the code :-

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)  mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_row, parent, false);
    }

    return row;
}
```

The country row XML is :--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameOfCountry"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:text="Country" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Now my question is once I check few of the check boxes in the list view and the scroll the list view, many other check boxes are automatically checked....

I know there is problem in getView but I'm not able to figure out where....

Also the problem is solved if I don't reuse the convert view. But that is a dumb idea...

Any thoughts.....

Comment: Read about view recycling. You need to set the properties of the right row when you reuse the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the ListView does recycling of views.  Essentially, it reuses some views that go off screen to make the new ones on screen to help with performance.  There are 2 ways of dealing with this:

1. Set the values of the views before you return the row.  For example, you would set the `nameOfCountry` and whether or not the checkbox is checked before the `return view` line.  To do this though, you need to keep track of what is checked.
2. Don't use the `convertview` and just inflate a new view every time.  This may result in a performance hit, but as long as the list isn't too long it shouldn't be too noticable (at least in my experience).  Simply igonre the `convertview` value

Comment: What type of adapter are you using/extending?  BaseAdapter, ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Do you still need example code?  I can put some in if you want.

Comment: Well, I did something with what i wanted to do, but yes if u can share some code, i'll be thankful... :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the state of the checkbox explicitly if you reuse an old `View`.